# How fast does one have to be to move several times in front of another human and be unnoticed?

Tags: the-eminence-in-shadow

In *The Eminence in Shadow* episode 2, Cid is "training" with Claire and when Claire is about to slash him, he moves so fast that he's able to side-step, slash his sword 4 times, go back to his original position, and pretend that he got hit. After the fact, Claire acts as if nothing abnormal happened, as if Cid had never done anything, but she feels a small chill on her neck (where Cid almost slashed).

The human eye can't see things moving faster than 550 mph (which would be ~1.6 the speed of sound).

But is moving at Mach 2 speed enough to replicate what Cid did? Or would it have to be a whole other scale like the speed of light?

I'm looking more for a ballpark rather than an exact number, just so I can understand what is Cid's speed.

[Cid slashes Claire 4 times and pretends nothing happened](https://youtu.be/wpvEu_HwlyM?si=7bZg2JUNmnhaptTh&t=23)

**At what speed does he move? Sound? Light?**

---

Other instances of his insane speed:

- [Shadow (Cid) disappears from a "War Goddess" sight and appears behind her, she can't focus on him like she can't focus on every single rain drop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NtYF-FhtyM)
- [Mundane Man (Cid) is fast enough to create after images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrWRMXHFQrg)

Comment: I found [this](https://news.mit.edu/2014/in-the-blink-of-an-eye-0116), which could suggest that less than the speed of sound would be fine with some assumptions. I guess there is a better SE for the question?

Comment: Probably way easier to do with magic tricks like instant hypnosis.